# Cannot use QueryBuilder with column name = "`GROUP`" in ormlite

Tags: java, sql, h2, ormlite, query-builder

The code

```
QueryBuilder<MyClass, String> builder = mnDao.queryBuilder();
builder.where().eq("`GROUP`", someGroup));
```

throws exception

> "Unknown column name '`GROUP`' in table MyClassTable"

I've tried to use escapeColumnName() from UpdateBuilder but the result is the same.
I could use raw queries, but they are not safe, because they don't provide placeholders.

The database is H2.

It looks like a bug in ormlite.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What about `"\"GROUP\""`, as names are quoted thus in H2? BTW  `"GROUP"` was tried?

Comment: @JoopEggen Just to be sure I've tried "\"GROUP\"" - no way. "GROUP"  also doesn't work.

Comment: The easiest fix might be to change the column name to something that's not a keyword in SQL.

Comment: @DonRoby You are genius! I thought that sql 'ALTER TABLE "MyClassTable" ALTER COLUMN `GROUP` RENAME TO GROUP1' is impossible, but it works. Please post it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right answer is to not do any quoting at all.  [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) automatically quotes all of the field and table names.  This is very database dependent for sure but H2 is my primary test database so I'm sure it works well in all cases that I know about for it.  As to why it didn't work for you I can't comment on.  If you post the query generated by ORMLite I may see the problem.

The pattern that is recommended is to define any columns that are to be used in queries as public strings.  For example:

```
protected static class Reserved {
    public static final String FIELD_NAME_GROUP = "group";
    ...
    @DatabaseField(columnName = FIELD_NAME_GROUP)
    String group;
    ...
}
```

Then when you query, you then use the `FIELD_NAME_GROUP` without any quoting and do:

```
QueryBuilder<Reserved, Integer> sb = dao.queryBuilder();
sb.where().eq(Reserved.FIELD_NAME_GROUP, "something");
...
```

I have good coverage of this in a couple of unit tests.  See the following test that I run across all of my database types that are supported.  Look for `testCreateReserverdTable()` and `testCreateReserverdFields()` methods and their associated classes in the [JdbcBaseDaoImplTest.java unit test](http://ormlite.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ormlite/ormlite-jdbc/trunk/src/test/java/com/j256/ormlite/dao/JdbcBaseDaoImplTest.java?revision=2598&view=markup).

Comment: Well, your answer doesn't explain why my code didn't work. Also, the test cases you are pointing doesn't look as tests for the case where reserved word is in WHERE part of sql query. Unfortunately I don't have time to test your answer myself. Just be sure that my test case will work. Thank you for the great orm tool.

Comment: No it doesn't explain it.  All I can do is demonstrate that it should work.   My test case _did_ use the `select` keyword in the `WHERE` but I've added more to have it also use `group` which works fine.

Comment: If you try just "group", please send me your debug output so I can see what query is being generated by ORMLite.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know ormlite, and it *ought* to have a way of quoting a name in a way that allows you to use odd table names, but the easiest fix for this sort of thing is to avoid using sql keywords as table names or column names.

If you can change the table name to something sql doesn't use for something else, it'll probably just work.